# Lab js + Javascriptmvc steal

Tags: javascriptmvc, labjs

Anybody used LabJs in conjunction with javascriptmvc steal? meaning looking for dependency loading in child level as well as taking advantage of LabJs async performance gains.

a.js

.....

steal(../b.js)
.then(../c.js) //c.js requires b.js and d.js to be loaded before it can load

b.js

.....

steal(../d.js) //(need to load d.js when b.js invoked, loading d.js for better classification and maintenance )

Any articles or experiences for labjs + steal will be great.

Answer (score 0):

steal is going to build your production app into a single JS file. You can load that file however you want.

Answer (score 0):

setting aside that steal builds a single file for you for the moment...

the concept of annotating dependencies nested inside each script means that, by itself, you cannot take full advantage of parallel loading, because the loader doesn't know what scripts that A depends on until it finishes loading A and can see that it needs B and C. Of course, once it knows about B and C, it can load those two in parallel, but it cannot load B and C in parallel with A.

the other issue is that LABjs (and most other dynamic script loaders) has, strictly speaking, non-blocking behavior, so if you load some scripts like this, you will have an issue:

A
  -- depends on B and C

D
  -- depends on A and E

When A finishes loading, and then you start loading B and C, you can't natively (without extra pre-effort) make D wait until B, and C (and thus A) are done.

The reasons behind this are quite complicated to explain, but suffice it to say, that scenario is problematic for dynamic loading with nested dependency annotation.

---

However, if you know about the dependency tree at the beginning (that is, you don't wait to load scripts to find out about their nested dependency annotations), you can easily take advantage of dynamic parallel loading while making sure order is preserved. You *can* easily do this:

B
C
A
E
D

and load all 5 of them in parallel, while still making sure they execute in that proper order as noted. The best way to figure out that dependency tree and the necessary order of execution is to have a build process that walks through all your scripts and figures out what the list is and its necessary order.

Using LABjs, that chain above would look like this:

$LAB.setOptions({AlwaysPreserveOrder:true}).script([B,C,A,E,D]);

Pretty simple and straightforward, assuming you know at the outset what that list/order is. Just have your build script drop that one line of code into your HTML page, and boom, you're good.

If you don't have such a build script to do that (I have my own that I've built for my various projects that need this type of thing), you have two choices:

1. Don't use **nested dependency annotation**. Manage your list of dependencies (the above list) yourself, and make sure it's in the right order. For a decade or more, that's how people using script-tags in browsers have worked just fine, so it's probably quite sufficient for the majority of sites. I have LABjs chains on many of my sites that I manage manually, and it's no problem at all, as do thousands of other sites which use LABjs.
2. Use a build script (like Steal) that just puts them all in one file (of course, it has to figure out the proper order too!). You don't get the parallel loading benefit. Bummer.

Hopefully this sheds some light on the issues at hand.